# How to upgrade slapd to 2.4.40?

Tags: apt, upgrade, openldap

I just found out, that connecting via the LDAP API like this

```
sudo ldapsearch -Q -LLL -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -b cn=config dn
```

[has a bug on `Ubuntu 15.04 vivid`/`openldap-2.4.31`](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openldap/+bug/1392018). But fortunately, on that bug report, I can find the message, that

> This bug was fixed in the package openldap - 2.4.40+dfsg-1ubuntu1

Now how can I upgrade my openLDAP to that specific version? I already did `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`. But my current openLDAP version remains `2.4.31`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 2.4.40 is currently only available for the next Ubuntu release *Wily* and there is no PPA with version 2.4.40.

You can download the [source code](https://code.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openldap) and apply a patch for [Utopic](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openldap/+bug/1392018/comments/6) and [Vivid](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openldap/+bug/1392018/comments/7).